# Seeing deleted posts -- a couple different use cases

Tags: discussion

I am curious if there is any facility for finding deleted posts.

1. One use case is to view deleted posts by a specific user, to see if there is a clear trend.  C.f. [this user](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/users/56148/), who appears to be making extensive use of an AI to "answer" various questions.
2. Another use case is to review suspected AI posts more generally.  With the advent of ChatGPT and other generative AI models, we are (and will be) seeing more and more posts coming from these engines.

Relatedly, is there any means of flagging a post as suspected AI content?  Would others find such a flag useful, and if so, how do we go about getting one set up?

Comment: I agree that there needs to be a flag for this, given that it’s a new site rule. I’ve been using the freeform text flag.

Comment: Re: new flag, [SO just got plagiarism flag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/423749/2821954), but whether it's intended for AI-generated posts or not is debatable. (Currently, [SO mods still recommend using a free-text flag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/423749/plagiarism-flag-and-moderator-tooling-has-launched-to-stack-overflow?cb=1#comment950923_423749))